# water use for blue spruce outside natural environment?

Tags: watering, landscaping, conifers

I live below the natural range of blue spruce in a hot grassland habitat.  How much water does a blue spruce need to thrive in this hot dry landscape?

Comment: Which USDA zone are you in, or alternatively, where are you in the world?

Comment: Where's the water table?

Comment: Please send a picture, patrice!  Your zone, your soil type, what other plants are in the vicinity...other trees, shade light conditions what you have added such as fertilizers, mulch, how did you plant your tree, when you planted your tree, was it balled and burlapped or was it in a pot or both?  Depending on your soil and how you planted your tree makes an awful lot of difference.  How big the root ball was...we all hesitate to answer until we know the basic facts.  Do not over water...underwatering is best until you are able to answer these questions.  Thanks!!

Comment: Welcome patrice! This is an interesting question, but we need more information in order to give you the answers you need. Since our site is different from others, I invite you to take the [tour] and visit the [help]. The [ask] page is a good place to start. For now, this question might get closed, which is explained [here](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions). If you come back, which we hope you do, feel free to edit the question and we can go from there!